# Confused creating FLS for Update

Tags: apex, fls

I'm creating an AppExchange App which has an Update operation to be performed. When put through the checkmarx I get the below error.

> Method saveMappingAssignment at line 65 of classes\FieldMappingController.cls gets user input from element profile_ids__c. This input is later concatenated by the application directly into a string variable containing SQL commands, without being validated. This string is then used in method saveMappingAssignment to query the database fm, at line 65 of classes\FieldMappingController.cls, without any additional filtering by the database. This could allow the user to tamper with the filter parameter.

The Same error is shown for `user_ids__c`.

Here is my Update code block.

```
  @AuraEnabled 
    public static Field_Mapping__c saveMappingAssignment(String recid,String userIds,String profileIds){

        String namespace = getNameSpace();
        namespace = String.isBlank(namespace) ? '' : namespace; 

        List<String> fieldsUsed = new List<String>{'Profile_IDs__c', 'User_IDs__c', 'Id'};
            try{
                if(FLSCheck.isAccessible(fieldsUsed, namespace+'Field_Mapping__c') && FLSCheck.isUpdateable(fieldsUsed, namespace+'Field_Mapping__c'))
                { 
                    Field_Mapping__c fm=new Field_Mapping__c(Id=recid);
                 if(profileIds!=null)
                     fm.Profile_IDs__c=profileIds;
                 if(userIds!=null)
                     fm.User_IDs__c=userIds;
                 update fm;
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }catch(Exception e){

                String[] msgstr = e.getMessage().split('Mapping already assigned to ');
                String mainmsg;

                if(msgstr != null && msgstr.size()==2){
                    mainmsg = 'Mapping already assigned to '+msgstr[1];
                }else{
                    mainmsg= e.getMessage();
                }

                AuraHandledException newex = new AuraHandledException(mainmsg); 
                system.debug('*********e.getMessage()'+mainmsg); 
                throw newex;
                return null;
            }
        return getRecordData(recid);
    }
```

and here is my FLSCheck class's Update block.

```
public static boolean isUpdateable(List<String> fieldNames, String objName){
    boolean isSafe = false;
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    SObjectType myObj = schemaMap.get(objName);
    if(myObj.getDescribe().isAccessible()){ 
        for(String fldName: fieldNames){
            SObjectField myField = myObj.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fldName);
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = myField.getDescribe();
            if(dfr.isUpdateable()){
                isSafe = true;
            }else{
                isSafe = false;
                break;
            }    
        }
    }else{
        isSafe = false;
    }
    return isSafe;
}
```

I'm unable to understand why I'm getting this error though I'm doing a FLSCheck.

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: P.S. you don't need to `return` after a `throw`, because the latter interrupts the flow of code and results in unreachable code.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the quick reply.. can you please let me know if that Is that causing the issue in FLS?

Comment: Looks like a false positive to me, at least based on the code you have posted. The scanner (at least in the past) did not parse Apex but rather pattern matches which meant that valid code was often reported as a security problem.

Comment: @KeithC Cool brother, I'll submit as it is to appexchange in that case 